# NSView prepareContent(in:)

Tags: responsive, smooth-scrolling

Forgive if this is a dumb question, I'm pretty new to mac programming.
I've read much on responsive scrolling and it all makes complete sense except when I override prepareContent(in:) in my document view, I receive the rectangles fine but NSGraphicsContext.current returns nil in the callback (obviously not the case during normal draw callback).
It's a simple setup: scrollview->clipview->document view.  No subview, no layers.  All have:
`override var isOpaque: Bool { return true }`
and
`NSView.isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling` returns true

I can't find a single piece of sample code using this anywhere and have scoured every bit of documentation I can find.
If no current context how is one supposed to render the content (which is just CG content - no OpenGL).
Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to render inside `prepareContent(in:)`, your regular `draw(_ dirtyRect:)` will be called including the overdraw regions. `prepareContent(in:)` is just for preparing, e.g. adding subviews, loading content and possibly adjusting the overdraw region if you want to.

For more information see WWDC session 215 Optimizing drawing and scrolling (from 2013)

Comment: Thanks for that 